# BigQUery SQL GROUP BY not grouping by date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the below query to GROUP BY "ReportingDate" but its not grouping the results.

```
SELECT WCode,Wname,ReportingDate,UnitOfMeasure,TAR,ACT,ACTA FROM `TABLE` WHERE ReportingDate = '2020-07-31' GROUP BY ReportingDate, WCode,Wname,UnitOfMeasure,TAR,ACT,ACTA
```

Current:

| WCode | Wname | ReportingDate | UnitOfMeasure | TAR | ACT | ACTA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 339629 | WrcA | 2020-07-31 | dollars | null | -39.77 | null |
| 339629 | WrcA | 2020-07-31 | dollars | null | null | -54.56 |

I want to GROUP BY the results so that I can add a new column to calculate the variance between ACT and ACTA

Output Required:

| WCode | Wname | ReportingDate | UnitOfMeasure | TAR | ACT | ACTA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 339629 | WrcA | 2020-07-31 | dollars | null | -39.77 | -54.56 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
SELECT WCode,Wname,ReportingDate,UnitOfMeasure,TAR, MAX(ACT) AS ACT, MAX(ACTA) AS ACTA 
FROM `TABLE` 
WHERE ReportingDate = '2020-07-31' 
GROUP BY ReportingDate, WCode,Wname,UnitOfMeasure,TAR
```

with output as

[image]